# extender bundle not registering blueprint services

Tags: osgi, equinox, blueprint-osgi

I have a standalone quinox container running and I have these following bundles installed and started:

[image]

And I can see these log messages in the console:

*org.ops4j.pax.logging.pax-logging-api[org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintExtender] : **Starting blueprint extender...**

org.ops4j.pax.logging.pax-logging-api[org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintEventDispatcher] : EventAdmin package is not available, 
                                                                                                       just don't use it

org.ops4j.pax.logging.pax-logging-api[org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintExtender] : No quiesce support is available, so blueprint components will not participate in quiesce operations

org.ops4j.pax.logging.pax-logging-api[org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintExtender] : **Blueprint extender started**

com.test.osgi.blueprint-service-api_1.0.0.1 bundle has my service interface.
 com.test.osgi.blueprint-service-impl_1.0.0.1 bundle has my service 
  implementation.

The META-INF headers for my com.test.osgi.blueprint-service-impl_1.0.0.1 bundle are:

> Bundle headers:
>   Bnd-LastModified = 1460382580049
>   Build-Jdk = 1.8.0_74
>   Built-By = schinnadurai
>   Bundle-Activator = com.test.osgi.blueprint.service.impl.BluePrintServiceImplBundleActivator
>   **Bundle-Blueprint = OSGI-INF/blueprint.xml**
>   Bundle-ManifestVersion = 2
>   Bundle-Name = blueprint-service-impl
>   Bundle-SymbolicName = com.test.osgi.blueprint-service-impl
>   Bundle-Version = 1.0.0.1
>   Created-By = Apache Maven Bundle Plugin
>   Embed-Dependency = *;scope=compile|runtime
>   Embed-Transitive = true
>   **Export-Service = com.test.osgi.blueprint.service.api.GreetingService**
>   import-Package = org.osgi.framework;version="[1.5,2)",com.test.osgi.blueprint.service.api;version="[1.0,2)"
>   Manifest-Version = 1.0
>   Tool = Bnd-2.1.0.20130426-122213

The blueprint.xml file inside this service impl bundle is :

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<blueprint xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0">
   
  <bean id="bluePrintServiceImpl" activation="eager"
    class="com.test.osgi.blueprint.service.impl.ServiceImpl"/>
    
  <service id="myGreetingService" ref="bluePrintServiceImpl" activation="eager"
    interface="com.test.osgi.blueprint.service.api.GreetingService"/>
   
</blueprint>
```

When I start the service impl bundle, there is no service is registered. Please see below:

> Id=158, Status=ACTIVE      Data Root=C:\tools\org.eclipse.osgi_3.6.1.R36x_v20100806\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\158\data
>    **No registered services.**
>    No services in use.
>    No exported packages
>    Imported packages
>       org.osgi.framework; version="1.5.0"
>       com.test.osgi.blueprint.service.api; version="1.0.0.1"
>    No fragment bundles
>    Named class space
>       com.test.osgi.blueprint-service-impl; bundle-version="1.0.0.1"[provided]
>    No required bundles

I installed a service client which uses this service. But it could not find a registered service.
Am I missing anything here. Did I miss any required blueprint extender bundles?

Thanks in advance.

## UPDATE:

I have tested my bundles in **WAS Liberty** and all my blueprint services are registered and referenced **successfully**. so it seems that I am missing some required bundles for blueprint services here in this standalone equinox setup

Comment: Where did you put the bluprint,xml inside the bundle?

Comment: Is there any logging at all relating to your bundle from Blueprint?

Comment: My blueprint.xml file is inside the OSGI-INF as follows:                  blueprint-service-impl-1.0.0.1.jar/
        >com /
        >META-INF /
        >OSGI-INF / blueprint.xml

Comment: I could not see any logging from blueprint relating to my bundle. I can see only my BundleActivator log messages.

Comment: I have tested my bundles in WAS Liberty and all my blueprint services are registered and referenced successfully.                                                      so it seems that I am missing some required bundles for blueprint services here in this standalone equinox setup.

Comment: Which bundles were missing in your standalone equinox setup? I have the same problems.